# Anything I place inside the div tag, doesn't get printed

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, google-api

I came across a code that is said to update only that piece of code, which is placed inside the `div` tag. I need to print the seconds left for `1-1-2013`. But I get to see nothing. Anything placed inside the `div` tag is not visible. Since I am not at hands with `JQuery` and `Ajax`, I am unable to spot my mistake.

```
<body bgcolor="#73AF59">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">

    </script>

    <audio  preload="auto" src="tones/Time-In-A-Bottle.mp3" loop autoplay> 

    </audio>

    <%! 
      GregorianCalendar newYear =  new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 1);  
      /*
       * 0 : January
       * 1 : 1st January
       * 2013 : year
       */           
    %>


<table width="100%">
<tr> 
  <td width="40%"> </td>
  <td> <img src="images/animations/pyear.gif" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="40%"> <center> <font face="Chiller" size="+6"> <br /> Countdown </font> </center> </td>
  <td>  <center> <font face="Chiller" size="+6"> <br /> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
            $('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
        <div id="load_tweets">

         <%= ( newYear.getTimeInMillis() - new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() ) / 1000 %>

        </div>
      </script>
      </font> </center>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="height:400px"  valign="bottom"> <img src="images/animations/3D_balloons.gif" /> 
        <em>This poor design and animations compiled by Suhail Gupta.</em>
            <audio style="visibility: hidden" > </audio>
  </td>
</tr>
<!-- !-->
```

The statement `<%= ( newYear.getTimeInMillis() - new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() ) / 1000 %>` , should print the seconds left for the arrival of 2013.

Comment: I have uploaded the complete code [HERE](http://suhail3.my3gb.com/nyblast%20%28copy%29.jsp)

Comment: `font` tags??  They are deprecated in html5. Use CSS

Comment: Scriptlet is executed once and won't be executed unless you refresh the current page and what does the  `$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");` do?

Comment: @AVD So Ajax and JSP Scriplet don't go hand in hand ? I mean ajax functionality cannot be extracted while I am using scriplets ?

Comment: JavaScript code is executed at client machine(web-browser) and JSP code will be executed at server JVM  (application server).

Comment: @AVD I know. But I was referring to Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print result (subtraction of mills of two date) on web-page at given interval you need to create a `servlet` that produce subtraction of mills and write Ajax routine in JSP to request that `servlet`.

**Servlet**

---

```
@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/test"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       double value=((double)(new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 1).getTimeInMillis() - new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()))/1000;
       PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
       response.setContentType("text/plain");
       pw.print(value);
       pw.flush();
    }
}
```

and page that request the servlet using `$.ajax` method:

**test-page.jsp**

---

```
 <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            setInterval(function(){  
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test',
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    }
                });
            },1000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to think:

1. You are missing the `doc ready` handler for the jQuery
2. You have placed your div inside of the `<script/>` tag
3. try with removing the `fadeIn`

So your code has to be like this:

```
<body bgcolor="#73AF59">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <audio  preload="auto" src="tones/Time-In-A-Bottle.mp3" loop autoplay></audio>

    <%! 
      GregorianCalendar newYear =  new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 1);  
      /*
       * 0 : January
       * 1 : 1st January
       * 2013 : year
       */           
    %>


<table width="100%">
<tr> 
  <td width="40%"> </td>
  <td> <img src="images/animations/pyear.gif" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="40%"> <center> <font face="Chiller" size="+6"> <br /> Countdown </font> </center> </td>
  <td>   
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){ // try to put in doc ready handler
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
            $('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php');
        }, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
      });
      </script>
      <center> 
      <font face="Chiller" size="+6"> <br />
        <div id="load_tweets">
         <%= ( newYear.getTimeInMillis() - new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() ) / 1000 %>
        </div> 
         </font> 
      </center>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="height:400px"  valign="bottom"> <img src="images/animations/3D_balloons.gif" /> 
        <em>This poor design and animations compiled by Suhail Gupta.</em>
            <audio style="visibility: hidden" > </audio>
  </td>
</tr>
<!-- !-->
```

or you can move this up just below jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){ // try to put in doc ready handler
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
            $('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php');
        }, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
      });
     </script>
```

Try this and see if this helps you.

Comment: no..it is not updating. I just tried copy pasting your above code

Comment: what do you have in the **`record_count.php`** file